# Looking for a story about a clockman?

Tags: story-identification

It’s been a few years but I remember reading an old (French?) novel about an old watch repairman who lives in a village. Somewhere in the story all the watches stop in the town and the repairman goes to a castle or something and finds a man with a clock as a head who was responsible. I’m not sure what else happens but I know it was published around the 19th century and it had some pretty cool black and white illustrations.
Thank you!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Are there any fantastic elements in the story?  Only works of science fiction and fantasy are on topic here.  If so, please [edit] the question to include them; if not you might be able to ask on [literature.se].

Comment: The man with a clock as a head who can stop all clocks?

Comment: @Adamant - Well, that all seems *painfully mundane* to me.